Form model events no longer available in Freeform V5
I have a custom plugin that relied on the Form Model Events from Freeform version 4, particularly the EVENT_AFTER_SAVE and the EVENT_AFTER_DELETE events. Does anyone know how to recreate this functionality now that the Form Model and those 2 specific events don't exist in version 5?
For what it is worth I do know that the old Form Model seems to have now been replaced by Solspace\Freeform\Form\Form.php but Solspace\Freeform\Events\Forms\SaveEvent.php and Solspace\Freeform\Events\Forms\DeleteEvent.php haven't been updated to reflect that.
